# Key adapter not working in JComponent

Tags: java, swing, focus, paint, jcomponent

I tried to do a little menu in which you could change the options with your keyboard, a created an inner class that extends from key adapter, and then adding it to the menu class, however i am not getting any response from the keyboard, could anybody help me fix this problem?

```
public class MenuWindow extends JComponent 
{
    private Rectangle2D.Float returnButton;
    private Rectangle2D.Float mainMenuButton;
    private Rectangle2D.Float restartButton;
    private Rectangle2D.Float highScoreButton;
    private int selectedButton;

    public MenuWindow  ()
    {
        selectedButton=0;
        mainMenuButton = new Rectangle2D.Float(25, 25, 200, 75);
        restartButton = new  Rectangle2D.Float(25, 125, 200, 75);
        highScoreButton = new Rectangle2D.Float( 25, 225, 200, 75);
        returnButton = new  Rectangle2D.Float( 25, 325, 200, 75);           
        this.addKeyListener(new MenuKeyInput());
        this.requestFocus();            
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D ) g;        
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.6f));         
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);           
        g2.fillRect(0, 0, 250, 425);
        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(14));
        g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2.drawRect(0, 0, 250, 425);            
        //draw buttons 
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.2f));
        g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);            
        g2.fill(mainMenuButton);
        g2.fill(restartButton);
        g2.fill(highScoreButton);
        g2.fill(returnButton);          
        // paint selected button
        paintSelectedButton(mainMenuButton, restartButton, highScoreButton, returnButton, g2);
    }

    public void paintSelectedButton(Rectangle2D.Float a,Rectangle2D.Float b,Rectangle2D.Float c,Rectangle2D.Float d, Graphics2D g)
    {
        g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.45f));
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        switch (selectedButton)
        {
        case 0:
            g.fill(a);
            break;
        case 1:
            g.fill(b);
            break;
        case 2:
            g.fill(c);
            break;
        case 3:
            g.fill(d);
            break;  
        }
    }
     //inner class
    public class MenuKeyInput extends KeyAdapter
    {
        public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e)
        {
            int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)System.exit(0);
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
            {
                selectedButton--;

                if (selectedButton == -1)
                {
                    selectedButton=3;
                }
                repaint();
            }
            else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
            {
                selectedButton++;
                if (selectedButton ==4)
                {
                    selectedButton=0;
                }
                repaint();
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

This is the main class i am using :

```
public static void main (String arg[])
{

    JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
    MenuWindow window = new MenuWindow();
    frame.add(window);

    frame.setSize(new Dimension(250, 425));
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setUndecorated(true);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: you could use  `Key Bindings`http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html .

Comment: I can't seem to recreate your problem. I tried running this code with my own main method and the graphics are being repainted properly. Do you have a main method that you can show?

Comment: The problem is two fold. 1- The JComponent is not focusable by default, so even requesting focus will,have no effect, because KeyListener will only ever generate key events if the component is focusable AND has focus, your component can never receive key events. 2- KeyListener, generally, isn't the best choice for this type of work. Use the key bindings api instead

Comment: You're also breaking the paint chain. Consider overriding the paintComponent method and make sure you're calling super.paintComponent before you perform any custom painting